# Parse OpenFoam files in Python

Tags: python, performance, parsing

I'm writing a Python parser for OpenFoam mesh files. When the mesh is big, I face performance issues.

Here is the format of the file describing the points:

```
/*--------------------------------*- C++ -*----------------------------------*\
| =========                 |                                                 |
| \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox           |
|  \\    /   O peration     | Version:  2.2.0                                 |
|   \\  /    A nd           | Web:      www.OpenFOAM.org                      |
|    \\/     M anipulation  |                                                 |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
FoamFile
{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
    class       vectorField;
    location    "constant/polyMesh";
    object      points;
}
// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //


10
(
(2.14633 0.955 -0.627026)
(2.14633 1.005 -0.627026)
(4.0935 0.955 -0.389604)
(4.0935 1.005 -0.389604)
(0.199157 0.955 -0.864447)
(0.199157 1.005 -0.864447)
(3.075 1.005 0.562347)
(3.11114 1.005 0.558563)
(3.075 0.955 0.562347)
(3.11114 0.955 0.558563)
)


// ************************************************************************* //
```

The file describing the tetrahedron points:

```
/*--------------------------------*- C++ -*----------------------------------*\
| =========                 |                                                 |
| \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox           |
|  \\    /   O peration     | Version:  2.2.0                                 |
|   \\  /    A nd           | Web:      www.OpenFOAM.org                      |
|    \\/     M anipulation  |                                                 |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
FoamFile
{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
    class       faceList;
    location    "constant/polyMesh";
    object      faces;
}
// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //


10
(
3(566037 390932 236201)
3(566037 146948 390932)
3(146948 236201 390932)
3(566037 236201 146948)
3(833456 434809 832768)
3(833456 832768 833463)
3(832768 434809 833463)
3(833456 833463 434809)
3(151487 504429 264888)
3(151487 264888 391870)
)


// ************************************************************************* //
```

Here is an example of boundary file:

```
/*--------------------------------*- C++ -*----------------------------------*\
| =========                 |                                                 |
| \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox           |
|  \\    /   O peration     | Version:  2.2.0                                 |
|   \\  /    A nd           | Web:      www.OpenFOAM.org                      |
|    \\/     M anipulation  |                                                 |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
FoamFile
{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
    class       polyBoundaryMesh;
    location    "constant/polyMesh";
    object      boundary;
}
// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

2
(
    object_surf
    {
        type            wall;
        physicalType    wall;
        nFaces          48738;
        startFace       9010058;
    }
    vacuum_surf
    {
        type            patch;
        physicalType    patch;
        nFaces          167218;
        startFace       9112924;
    }
)
```

And the class I wrote to parse these files:

```python
class ParsedMesh:
    """ rep is the path to the directory containing the mesh files """
    def __init__(self,rep):

        def readFile(ficName):
            """ readFile: read a file to parse. Returne a list of the lines of the file without "\n" and ";" character """
            fic = open(os.path.join(rep,ficName),"r")
            tmp = [ line.replace(';','').replace('\n','').strip() for line in fic ] # delete \n and ;
            return [ line for line in tmp if line != '' ] # don't return the empty lines

        def parseHeader(self):
            res = {}
            headerSection = False
            ### header parsing
            for el in self.fileContent:
                if el == "FoamFile":
                    headerSection = True
                    continue
                if headerSection == True:
                    if el == "{":
                        continue
                    elif el == "}":
                        headerSection = False
                        return res
                    else:
                        tmpEl = el.replace('"','').split()
                        res[tmpEl[0]] = tmpEl[1]
                        continue

        def parseBoundaryFile(self):
            self.fileContent = readFile("boundary")
            self.parsedMesh["boundary"]= {}
            self.parsedMesh["boundary"]["sections"]= {}
            # header
            self.parsedMesh["boundary"]["header"] = parseHeader(self)
            ## body
            boundarySection = False
            boundaryInnerSection = False
            for el in self.fileContent:
                if el.split()[0] == "(": # beginning of the values section
                    boundarySection = True
                    continue
                if el.split()[0] == ")": # end of the values section
                    boundarySection = False
                    break
                if el == "{":
                    boundaryInnerSection = True
                    continue
                if el == "}":
                    boundaryInnerSection = False
                    continue
                # read values
                if boundarySection == True:
                    if boundaryInnerSection == False:
                        boundName = el
                        self.parsedMesh["boundary"]["sections"][boundName] = {}
                        continue
                    else:
                        tmpEl = el.split()
                        self.parsedMesh["boundary"]["sections"][boundName][tmpEl[0]] = tmpEl[1]
                        continue

        def parsePointsFile(self):
            self.fileContent = readFile("points")
            self.parsedMesh["points"]= {}
            # header
            self.parsedMesh["points"]["header"] = parseHeader(self)
            ## body
            pointsSection = False
            pointNumber = 0
            self.parsedMesh["points"]["valuesList"] = []
            for el in self.fileContent:
                if el == "(": # beginning of the value section
                    pointsSection = True
                    continue
                if el == ")": # end of the value section
                    pointsSection = False
                    break
                # read the values
                if pointsSection == True:
                    pointNumber += 1
                    self.parsedMesh["points"]["valuesList"].append(numpy.array([float(el2) for el2 in el[1:-1].split()]))
                    continue

        def parseFacesFile(self):
            self.fileContent = readFile("faces")
            self.parsedMesh["faces"]= {}
            # header
            self.parsedMesh["faces"]["header"] = parseHeader(self)
            ## body
            pointsSection = False
            pointNumber = 0
            self.parsedMesh["faces"]["valuesList"] = []
            for el in self.fileContent:
                if el == "(": # beginning of the value section
                    pointsSection = True
                    continue
                if el == ")": # end of the value section
                    pointsSection = False
                    break
                # read the values
                if pointsSection == True:
                    pointNumber += 1
                    self.parsedMesh["faces"]["valuesList"].append([int(el2) for el2 in el[2:-1].split()])
                    continue

        self.parsedMesh = {}
        self.fileContent = []
        parseBoundaryFile(self)
        parsePointsFile(self)
        parseFacesFile(self)
```

Any idea allowing a performance improvement is appreciated. Any other comment is also welcome (I'm a physicist using Python, so probably making a lot of obvious mistakes).

Comment: Can you post an example of a boundary file, too?

Comment: I edited the post. :) Note that the points, faces and boundary values are not correct in the examples i give. But this is not important for the parsing work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. Follow pep8.  Your code is pretty good already, but your naming in particular is not correct.
2. Although I can see the advantage of grouping everything into a class, the individual file parsers are not directly dependent on the class.  I would split those out into their own functions.  This will make testing in particular easier.  You can then have wrapper methods in the class that call the parser functions.
3. You are loading every file completely into a list.  This takes a lot of memory for large files.  Worse, it requires parsing the entire list twice, once for the header and once for the body.  This is likely a big source of your performance issues.  It would be much more memory-efficient to iterate over the lines in the file.  I would recommend turning the reader into a generate that takes an iterator (which will usually be the file, but could be arbitrary lists of strings for testing), does the stripping, yields the stripped line, and skips empty lines.  This has the added advantage that it will keep track of your progress, so you don't need to go back and read through the header again when you want to parse the body.
4. If you use a generator, you can create a for loop that runs until it reaches the part you want, then breaks, then you can have a second for loop that picks up where the first left off.  This will greatly reduce the number of `if` tests you have to do.
5. You are parsing the list of numbers yourself.  Don't, numpy has a `fromstring` function that can parse a string to a numpy array for you.  It is much faster than your approach.  This is also likely a major source of performance issues.
6. You should always use `with` for opening files.  This safely closes them even when there is an error.  In the default Python version, files are closed automatically when the function exits, but that doesn't necessarily happen in other Python implementations like Pypy.  It is much safer to use `with` to close the files exactly when you intend to.
7. You can use tuple unpacking to split the lines for your dicts.  So `key, value = el.split()`.
8. You create a class, but then parse everything into a single `dict` that holds everything.  That defeats the purpose of having a class.  You should either parse the components into class attributes, or you should just use functions and return a single `dict`.
9. You hard-code the file names.  I would make the file names arguments, with the default argument being the default name.
10. `rep` is a directory, not a repetition.  The repetition may be in the directory name, but there is no reason it has to be.  So this is stylistic, but I would call it `dirname` or something.  There is no reason to mentally limit how you organize your files like that.
11. You make all the parsers subfunctions of `__init__`.  This again defeats the purpose of having a class.  They should be methods.
12. Your classes should derive from `object`.

So overall, here is how I would structure the code:

```
def clean_lines(lines):
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip().strip(';')
        if not line:
            continue
        yield line


def consume_lines(lines, targ):
    for line in lines:
        if line ==  targ:
            return


def header_parser(lines):
    consume_lines(lines, '{')

    res = {}
    for line in lines:
        if line == '}':
            break
        key, value = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        res[key] = value.strip('"')

    return res


def boundary_parser(lines):
    consume_lines(lines, '(')

    sections = {}
    for line in lines:
        if line == ')':
            break
        if line != '{':
            name = line
            sections[name] = {}
            continue
        for subline in lines:
            if subline == '}':
                break
            key, value = subline.split(maxsplit=1)
            sections[name][key] = value

    return sections


def points_parser(lines):
    consume_lines(lines, '(')

    points = []
    for line in lines:
        if line == ')':
            break
        points.append(np.fromstring(line[1:-1], sep=' '))
    return points


def faces_parser(lines):
    consume_lines(lines, '(')

    faces = []
    for line in lines:
        if line == ')':
            break
        faces.append(np.fromstring(line[2:-1], dtype=np.int32, sep=' '))

    return faces


class ParsedMesh(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname
        self.parse_boundary_file()
        self.parse_points_file()
        self.parse_faces_file()

    def _parser(self, parser, fname, dirname):
        if dirname is None:
            dirname = self.dirname
        if dirname:
            fname = os.path.join(dirname, fname)
        with open(fname) as fobj:
            lines = clean_lines(fobj)
            header = header_parser(lines)
            parsed = parser(lines)
        return parsed, header

    def parse_boundary_file(self, fname='boundary', dirname=None):
        self.boundary, self.boundary_hdr = self._parser(boundary_parser,
                                                        fname=fname,
                                                        dirname=dirname)

    def parse_points_file(self, fname='points', dirname=None):
        self.points, self.points_hdr = self._parser(points_parser,
                                                    fname=fname,
                                                    dirname=dirname)

    def parse_faces_file(self, fname='faces', dirname=None):
        self.faces, self.faces_hdr = self._parser(faces_parser,
                                                  fname=fname,
                                                  dirname=dirname)
```

Comment: `line.strip(';').strip()` should be `line.strip().strip(';')`, or perhaps `strip('\n ;')`

Comment: usefull post! I just had to make a few changes in split() calls because i use python 2.7 Now i will study your comments thx!

Comment: JanneKarila: indeed there was a little error in this line. Your proposal fixes it.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Maybe `strip('\n ;')` is more general (for example with `str = "hello world ;  \n"` ?

Comment: @user59330  The reason I don't like that approach is that it won't handle all whitespace.

Comment: I don't get it. Could you give an example ?

Comment: Your version won't handle tabs, but `split()` will.  There are also a couple dozen other unicode whitespace characters your code won't handle but `split` will.